# How to manually dismiss UIViewController.popoverPresentationController

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad

For iPad, when in portrait mode, I leave my left view controller(master controller) hidden and only show its popoverPresentationController. This works fine.
But when in landscape mode, I want my master controller to show in full view, and its popoverPresentationController to be hidden. But this seems not possible. I tried

```
[self.masterViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:self.masterViewController.popoverPresentationController completion:nil];
```

But this does not work. The left pane is blank. I tried to add these two lines after the popover is dismiss in the above code, and still nothing on the left pane:

```
[self.masterViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:self.masterViewController.popoverPresentationController completion:nil];
```

Anyone knows how to manually dismiss the popoverPresentationController just like a user clicks outside of the popover?

Comment: I made a mistake in the above code. In the second code block, I added these: [self.masterViewController viewWillAppear:NO];
            [self.masterViewController viewDidAppear:NO];

Comment: I removed the previous code, and added this, and it solved the problem: self.masterViewController.popoverPresentationController.presentedView.hidden = YES;

Comment: However, clicking on any item in self.masterViewController makes the left pane blank again.

Comment: I think I know the reason that the left pane is blank is because when the screen is rotated to landscape, no click action is performed outside the popoverPresentationController to dismiss the popover. So, when I click the screen after the rotation, it does the dismissing action and everything disappears. I am thinking about adding a manual dismissing method when the rotation just starts, but I don't know what method exists to dismiss the popoverPresentationController.

Comment: I finally got this working by added this when rotation occurs: [self.masterViewController.popoverPresentationController.presentedViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];

Comment: If you think this question (and its solution) is also useful for others, please edit it as required and provide an answer by yourself, so that the question is marked as answered. If you think the question is not so useful, please simply delete it.

Answer (score 0):

I use this code in the parent view controller :

```
IdentifyDeviceViewController *vc=[[IdentifyDeviceViewController alloc]init];    
vc.modalPresentationStyle=UIModalPresentationPopover;
vc.preferredContentSize = CGSizeMake(414, 672);    vc.popoverPresentationController.sourceRect=CGRectMake(self.view.bounds.origin.x, self.view.bounds.origin.y+190, 0, 0);
vc.popoverPresentationController.permittedArrowDirections = UIPopoverArrowDirectionUp;
vc.popoverPresentationController.sourceView=self.view;
vc.popoverPresentationController.delegate=self;
[self.navigationController presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];
```

and then use this code in IdentifyDeviceViewController for backTap:

```
- (void)backTap {
    [self.popoverPresentationController.presentedViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).